# for loop not looping through arraylist

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I can get the following arraylist to be displayed but I thought that my for loop should be done correctly but it is not decrementing......

```
  DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Popular Clinics"); // getReference() is the root
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.clear();
            // displayList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {



               int count = (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount()-1;

                for (int i = count; i >= 0; i--) {

                    list.add(String.valueOf(snapshot.child(String.valueOf(i)).getValue()));

                    //    displayList.add(snapshot.getValue());


                   }
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: So what value has `count` when you enter the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is not counting because in this :

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

           int count = (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount()-1;

        ....

               }
```

you are cycling through THE CHILDREN of the snapshot which have no children themselves which means this:

```
int count = (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount()-1;
```

returns -1

So replace your loop with this and try:

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot) {

      list.add(snapshot.getValue());
     
}
```

Comment: I have got it working.... but how do you remove unwanted characters in an arraylist?

Comment: I tried the remove method but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by unwanted characters? you mean chars in a String? or elements in an Arraylist?

Comment: I think the symbols come from the arraylist function.... []... can we remove this or is it part of the code that can't be removed?

Comment: i don't understand your question. you need to explain more possibly with some examples

Comment: I have attached a picture but I think that is part of the arralist output

Comment: not sure if we can remove it because if I do remove("Ringwood"), then it works